# How to be sure that we can span all the periodic functions with a Fourier series?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, fourier-series

The set of functions $$B = \left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \cos\left(\frac{2\pi n t}{T}\right) \mid n \in \mathbb{N}, \sin\left(\frac{2\pi n t}{T}\right) \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$$ is a set of othonormal vectors with the scalar product $\langle\ f,g\rangle =\frac{2}{T}\int_{0}^{T} f(t)g(t) \,dt $.

My question is how can we be sure that this set of vector is a basis for all possible $T$-periodic function? Why can't we find other functions orthonormal to the vectors in $B$?

My point with this question is to understand why Fourier said that all real $T$-periodic function can be written as a combination of the vectors in $B$. It is clear that once you have shown that $B$ is a basis for all these functions, then of course you can write any of these functions in the basis $B$.

I would accept a non-rigourous explanation, if it makes intuitively sense. Please try (if possible) to explain the concepts intuitively rather than with complicated mathematical terms.

Comment: This is a basic theorem in the theory of Fourier series. Ref. Theorem 2.4.1 in Fourier Series by Edwards.

Comment: Let google be your friend and search for "dirichlet theorem fourier". Sorry, it cannot be explained in a few words.

Comment: One has to be a little more careful with wording here.  In particular, trigonometric polynomials are dense in the space of continuous functions but do not form a basis there (i.e. Fourier series converges point wise almost everywhere but not uniformly). On the other hand, in $L^p,  1< p < \infty$ they are basis, that is converge in suitable norm.

Answer (score 4):

To simplify notation let me use $2\pi$ periodic functions and set $S^1={\Bbb R}/ 2\pi {\Bbb Z}$.

It is difficult to show the result directly using $L^2(S^1)$ functions. Instead you could first consider a dense subspace of smooth functions. You will need to know e.g. that $C^2(S^1)$ functions are dense in $L^2(S^1)$. Now, if $f$ is a periodic $C^2$ function then its Fourier-series converges uniformly to the function itself.
Here are the steps in a proof: Let $a_k$, $k\geq 0$ and $b_k$, $k\geq 1$ denote the respective Fourier coefficients. The $n$'th partial sum is then given by
$$ f_n(x) = \frac12 a_0 + \sum_{k=1}^n (a_k \cos (kx) + b_k \sin(kx) ) = 
  \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(t)\left[ \frac12 + \sum_{k=1}^n \cos k(x-t) \right] dt $$
which after a change of variables $t=x+u$ leads to
$$ f_n(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi  f(x+u) \frac{\sin \, (n+\frac12)u}{\sin  \, \frac12 u} du$$
and then
$$ f_n(x)-f(x)= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi  \frac{f(x+u)-f(x)}{\sin  \, \frac12 u}  \sin \left((n+\frac12)u \right)du.$$
The fraction in the last integral is uniformly continuous (in fact $C^1$) in $x$ and $u$ which implies that the integral goes uniformly to zero as $n\to +\infty$. Thus the trigonometric polynomial $f_n\to f$ uniformly.

Approximating $L^2$ functions by $C^2$ functions,  the rest follows. For example any $L^2$ function which is orthogonal to all of the above basis elements must equal zero a.e., Parseval's identity etc...

EDIT: With hints for the above calculations:

$$ \cos(kx-kt)= \cos(kx)\cos(kt) + \sin(kx)\sin(kt).$$
$$\sin (\frac{u}{2}) \left(\frac12 + \sum_{k=1}^n \cos(ku)\right) = \frac12 \left( \sin(\frac{u}2) + \sum_{k=1}^n (\sin(k+\frac12)u - \sin(k-\frac12)u \right)$$

For a periodic $C^1$ function $\phi$ (integration by parts):
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \phi(t)\sin\left((n+\frac12)u\right)du = \int_{-\pi}^\pi \phi'(t) \frac{\cos\left((n+\frac12)u\right)}{n+\frac12} \; du $$

Comment: I don't get what you did in the first equality:  $\frac12 a_0 + \sum_{k=1}^n (a_k \cos (kx) + b_k \sin(kx) ) = 
  \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(t)\left[ \frac12 + \sum_{k=1}^n \cos k(x-t) \right] dt$ And it is also not clear how the change of variable changes that sum of cosines into $\frac{\sin \, (n+\frac12)u}{\sin  \, \frac12 u}$ Neither why it goes to 0 when n goes to infinity. So basically I didn't get anything. Maybe I'm to dumb for that. But I feel you missed a lot of steps

Comment: I upvoted. Still, there is an important comment I would like to make here. While it is true that you can extend this result to $L^2$ by density, that step is not trivial, as this answer could suggest. The space of $C^2$ functions is also dense, in the uniform norm, in the space of continuous functions. However, you cannot conclude that all Fourier series of continuous functions converge at all points; that is false.

Comment: @NicolasSchmid: many of the missing computations are here; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel (I don't think you are dumb)

Comment: @NicolasSchmid I have put some further hints for the calculations. A full proof is typically something like a 2 hours lecture course at 2nd or 3rd year undergraduate and using some prerequisites on Lebesque integrals. To condense it into a single post is not easy.

Comment: Thank you for the update, I checked a bit what is on wikipedia about convergence of Fourier series and Dirichlet kernel. It indeed seems a good way to show the convergence of Fourier series, but it requires to much things I don't know yet. So I upvoted but don't accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading Chapter 4 of Walter Rudin's book *[Real and Complex Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070542341)* for a concise, rigorous and step by step proof of the completeness of trigonometric functions. Theorem 4.24 and 4.25 (in 3rd edition) are exactly what you are looking for. For the sake of brevity, I will transcribe a *part* of the text:

**4.24 The Completeness of the Trigonometric System** Theorem 4.18 shows that the maximality (or completeness) of the trigonometric system will be proved as soon as we can show that the set of all trigonometric polynomials is dense in $\mathcal L^2(T)$. Since $C(T)$ is dense in $\mathcal L^2(T)$, by Theorem 3.14 (note that $T$ is compact), it suffices to show that to every $f \in C(T)$ and to every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a trigonometric polynomial $P$ such that $\left\lVert f - P\right\rVert_2 < \epsilon$. Since $\left\lVert g\right\rVert_2 \le \left\lVert g\right\rVert_\infty$ for every $g \in C(T)$, the estimate $\left\lVert f - P\right\rVert_2 < \epsilon$ will follow from $\left\lVert f - P\right\rVert_\infty < \epsilon$, and it is this estimate which we shall prove.

*Please refer to p. 90 of the 3rd ed.*

**4.25 Theorem** If $f \in C(T)$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there is a trigonometric polynomial $P$ such that
$$|f(t) - P(t) | < \epsilon$$
for every real $t$.

Comment: Thank you for the references, but I can't afford to spend 150$ for the book for this proof. I upvote your answer but don't accept it, since it doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: @NicolasSchmid you are welcome. Actually, you won't need to spend that money on this, despite the fact that it's the reference that almost all the folks on this site praise and cherish! The pdf version is freely available on some sites if you just google the words "Rudin real and complex analysis". I am not allowed to share the link, but it's there.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem can be applied to prove that the $\cos(2\pi mt/T)$ and $\sin(2\pi nt/T)$ trig functions have as their $L^2$-Hilbert-span the whole $L^2$ space of periodic functions on $[0,T]$, where $S^1$ is viewed as $[0,T]$ with endpoints identified.

As a reference, see in Terry Tao's analysis book An Epsilon of Room, Volume I (an online version is available at his blog post [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/books/an-epsilon-of-room-pages-from-year-three-of-a-mathematical-blog/)) the comment following the statement of Theorem 1.12.4 (Plancherel Theorem for compact Abelian groups), specifically the first item about when $G$ is a torus; the case of interest here is when $G$ is $S^1$ (the "1-torus"), since we can view periodic functions on $[0,T]$ as functions on $S^1$. See Theorem 1.10.18 in that book for the Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

---

Here is an outline of how to apply Stone-Weierstrass to prove that the Hilbert-span of the trig functions $\sin(2\pi mt / T),\cos(2\pi n t,T)$ for $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ is all of the $L^2$ space of periodic functions on $[0,T]$.

For convenience, view the $L^2$ space of periodic functions on $[0,T]$ as the space of $L^2$ functions on $S^1$; here $S^1$ is viewed as $[0,T]$ with endpoints identified. Similarly, view the space of periodic continuous functions on $[0,T]$ as the space $C(S^1)$ of continuous functions on $S^1$.

We want to show the trig functions have $L^2$-Hilbert-span equal to all of $L^2(S^1)$.
This means we want to show the set of "countable linear combinations" (with coefficients forming an $\ell^2$, i.e. square-summable, sequence; see Exercise 1.4.18 of Tao's book) of the trig functions is all of $L^2(S^1)$.

To show this spanning property, it suffices to show that the set of *finite* linear combinations of the trig functions has $L^2$-closure equal to all of $L^2(S^1)$.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of *finite* linear combinations of the trigonometric functions $\cos(2\pi mt/T)$ and $\sin(2\pi nt/T)$ for $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Our aim is to show $\mathcal{A}$ is ($L^2$-)dense in $L^2(S^1)$.
This is where Stone-Weierstrass can be used.

The following are the conditions needed for Stone-Weierstrass to be applied.

- We can show $\mathcal{A}$ "separates points", i.e. for any two points $t_1,t_2 \in S^1$ with $t_1 \neq t_2$ there is $f \in \mathcal{A}$ with $f(t_1) \neq f(t_2)$.
- We can show $\mathcal{A} \subset C(S^1)$ is a unital subalgebra (also preserved by pointwise complex conjugation, if we allow complex linear combinations) of $C(S^1)$, the set of continuous functions on $S^1$.

Note: that $\mathcal{A} \subset C(S^1)$ is a *unital subalgebra* means basically that the constant functions are in $\mathcal{A}$ and also $\mathcal{A}$ is preserved by addition and multiplication of functions. (That $\mathcal{A}$ is preserved by multiplication may be easier to see if you use $e^{\pm 2\pi imt/T}$ as an alternative to $\cos(2\pi m t/T),\sin(2\pi m t/T)$, though this would require complex linear combinations; alternatively, one can use the trig addition formulas.)

Now, applying Stone-Weierstrass, we can say $\mathcal{A}$ is dense for the uniform topology in $C(S^1)$, the continuous functions on $S^1$, where $S^1$ is viewed as $[0,T]$ with endpoints identified.

All that remains now is to use the following:

1. This implies $\mathcal{A}$ is also dense in $C(S^1)$ for the $L^2$ norm; indeed the $L^2$ norm is $\leq$ $\sqrt{T}$ times the $L^\infty$ norm (i.e. uniform norm) on $S^1$, viewed as $[0,T]$ with endpoints identified.
2. And $C(S^1)$ is already dense in $L^2(S^1)$ for the $L^2$ norm.
   E.g.: $L^2$ functions can be $L^2$-approximated by finite linear combinations of characteristic functions (meaning, functions which are 1 on some measurable subset $E \subset S^1$ and 0 outside that set $E$), which in turn can be $L^2$-approximated by continuous functions in whichever manner.

Then we can conclude $\mathcal{A}$ is $L^2$-dense in $L^2(S^1)$. In other words $\mathcal{A} = \mathrm{finitary}\textrm{-}\mathrm{span}(\{\textrm{trig functions}\})$ has $L^2$-closure equal to all of $L^2(S^1)$. Thus the trig functions indeed $L^2$-Hilbert-span all of $L^2(S^1)$.

---

Finally, since the above shows that the trig functions are an $L^2$-Hilbert-spanning set for $L^2(S^1)$, and the trig functions are $L^2$-orthonormal which can be proved with some straightforward definite integrals, we may conclude the trig functions are a Hilbert basis for $L^2(S^1)$, viewed alternately as the $L^2$ space of periodic functions on $[0,T]$.

Note: the Fourier series for an $L^2$ function $f$ converges to $f$ only in the $L^2$ sense. I think this may not be a pointwise convergence in general, as has been pointed out in Balaji sb's answer.

Answer (score 0):

$f_{FT}(x)=\sum_n a_n cos(nx)+b_n sin(nx) = \sum_n \int f(t)cos(nt) cos(nx) dt +\int f(t)sin(nt) sin(nx) dt $
$= \int f(t) (\sum_n cos(nt) cos(nx) + sin(nt) sin(nx)) dt $ 
$= \int f(t) (\sum_n cos(n(t-x)) dt $ 
$= \int f(t) Re(\sum_{n} exp(in(t-x)))  dt $ 
$= \int f(t) \delta(t-x)  dt $ 
$= f(x) $

for the last equality refer: http://web.mit.edu/8.03-esg/watkins/8.03/deltf.pdf

There are conditions in which i can swap integral and infinite summation. So i am assuming $f$ satisfies all those conditions.

Edited:
Now coming to ur question: Can all periodic functions be written as fourier series. This boils down to the fact does the proof i gave works for all possible periodic functions. Answer is No. Read Section 1.1 : [http://math.iisc.ernet.in/~veluma/fourier.pdf](http://math.iisc.ernet.in/%7Eveluma/fourier.pdf) where the author mentions that it is possible to construct continuous periofic function whose fourier series differs from function at a particular point. But all hope is not lost. See theorem 1.1 in the same link where the author mentions that the set of all fourier expansions or the space spanned by the basis u have given is dense in $C[0,1]$. Hope this helps

Comment: I know what a Fourier series is, my question is why it work. I don't see the explanation to why they form a complete orthonormal basis, in other words, why it is impossible to find another periodic function that is orthogonal to all the vectors in the basis.

Comment: If there is a function $\psi$ orthonormal to all the basis u mentioned, then that function $\psi$ cant be represented by the fourier series but as u can see for example any continuous and differentialble function can be represented as a fourrier series by the proof i gave. So if there is an orthonormal element outside ur basis then it will be strange function.

Comment: Also complex exponentials (or the set of all fourier expansions) are dense in $C[0,1]$. This can be seen by Stone Wierstrass theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

Comment: See Theorem 1.1 in http://math.iisc.ernet.in/~veluma/fourier.pdf

Comment: @NicolasSchmid hope above comments of mine are useful.

Comment: @NicolasSchmid i have edited my answer. check it out